# How to access the constructor value outside the constructor

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 . In my project, get the json content using http.get() method and assigned it to a variable. I want to acces these variable value outside the constructor ..How can I make it possible ?

In my component page I used..

```js
public result;

  constructor(private http : Http){
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{ this.result = data}); 
  }
  
  // I want to acces this.result outside the constructor and assigned to a public variable
  
  public b = JSON.stringify(this.result);
  
  // but it is not working
```

How can I access this?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot know how long it takes to execute this and when the variable is available, so move the request to a method and call that method when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, why can't you do this?

```
  public result;
  public b;

  constructor(private http : Http){
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{ 
        this.result = data;
        this.b = JSON.stringify(this.result);
     }); 
  }
```

If you need to set it's value and then do something with it you can just call a method in the completion handler for the get request:

```
  constructor(private http : Http){
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{ 
        this.result = data;
        this.b = JSON.stringify(this.result);
     },
     err => console.log(err),
     () => {
         doStuffAndBisSet();
     }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this issue because the data is not ready yet, the subscribe method returns the data from a different thread, and when you assign this.result = data, it is too late, i.e. you are using this.result before .subscribe() finishes (and actually assigns the data).

I'm not sure if this is the best method, but what you can do is assign the .map method to a variable, and outside the constructor call the .subscribe method from your variable.

So you can do this:

```
public result;
constructor(private http : Http)
{
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
    .map(response => response.json());
    //.subscribe(data =>{ this.result = data}); comment this out 
}

// I want to acces this.result outside the constructor and assigned to a public variable
public myMethod()
{
    this.result.subscribe(data =>
    {
       console.log(data);
       //do what you want here.
    };
 }
```